# Choose the way to make App.js between using the function or using the class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, expo, native

I want to make some native applications with react expo. But I can't choose the way to make App.js between using the function or using the class. My friend says that it is better to use the function in the react web, but he doesn't know about react-native. Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: Generally you could use either or both, usually people using function based react components when they are pretty small and does not need any state or extra functionality. As far as I know, considered better practice to use class everywhere because you can extend your code without problem and everything will be/could be consistent. Personally I prefer class based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> `tl;dr` Use functional components.

If you plan on using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), you must use functional components.

Furthermore, if you are using [Expo SKD v38](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-38-is-now-available-ab6cd30ca2ee), you will find that using functional components is a lot easier because the Expo team have rewritten all their documentation to use FC.

Finally, a personal preference: you should also use TypeScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is correct, for reactjs the current recommendation is to use functional components. For react native, a lot of packages are using the class based components so I do understand where you’re coming from with this question. My advice is to use the functional based approach in both react and react native, for consistency.
If you check the expo documentation you’ll see both approaches in their examples so it’s safe to say that going for the functional based components is a good decision.

Answer (score 0):

Functional components are newer and the recommended way to go. But there shouldn't be a big difference, because the new React Hooks are the replacement for Higher Order Componnents. Only disadvantage are old resources wich used class components, but thats really rare.